# Python - Split xml and add original root note

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have complex XML that contains sales transactions.

```
<SALES ..some attributes..>
    <TRANSACT Type="RETAIL">
        <OTHER TAGS>
        </OTHER TAGS>
    </TRANSACT>
    <TRANSACT Type="POS">
        <OTHER TAGS>
        </OTHER TAGS>
    </TRANSACT>
</SALES>
```

I want to split it like:

```
<SALES ..some attributes..>
    <TRANSACT Type="RETAIL">
        <OTHER TAGS>
        </OTHER TAGS>
    </TRANSACT>
</SALES>
<SALES ..some attributes..>
    <TRANSACT Type="POS">
        <OTHER TAGS>
        </OTHER TAGS>
    </TRANSACT>
</SALES>
```

I am using below code to get child elements as below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('/tmp/hemant/file.xml')

for elem in root.findall('.//TRANSACT'):
    trans = ET.tostring(elem)
    #print trans
    if 'Type="RETAIL"' in trans:
        print "RETAIL_SALE"
    if 'Type="POS"' in trans:
        print "POS_SALE"
```

How to add parent  node coming from original file to each child?

Thanks

Comment: Is it guaranteed that in the original xml-file there is only one `<SALES>` node ?

Comment: Yes.SALES will be always there.

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working solution on python 2.7.10

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_str = '''
<SALES attr1="1" attr2="2">
    <TRANSACT Type="RETAIL">
        <OTHER_TAGS_RETAIL>
            <OTHER_TAG_RETAIL>
                I am OTHER_TAG RETAIL 1
            </OTHER_TAG_RETAIL>
        </OTHER_TAGS_RETAIL>
    </TRANSACT>
    <TRANSACT Type="POS">
        <OTHER_TAGS_POS>
            <OTHER_TAG_POS>
             I am OTHER_TAG POS 1
            </OTHER_TAG_POS>
            <OTHER_TAG_POS>
             I am OTHER_TAG POS 2
            </OTHER_TAG_POS>
        </OTHER_TAGS_POS>
    </TRANSACT>
</SALES>
'''

xml = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
new_root_element = ET.Element('root')
root_element_tag = xml.tag
for transact in xml.findall('.//TRANSACT'):
    sub_element = ET.SubElement(new_root_element, root_element_tag, xml.attrib)
    sub_element.append(transact)

print ET.tostring(new_root_element)
```

Comment: Hi MA1, you solution working for string holding XML inside it. thanks for that. However I am reading the file from path for which this code is not working. I have added necessary namespace references. my tweaked code: `root = ET.parse('/tmp/hemant/file.xml')
new_root_element = ET.Element('root')
root_element_tag = root.getroot()

for elem in root.findall('.//ixretail:Transaction', ns_ixretail):
 sub_element = ET.SubElement(new_root_element, root_element_tag, root_element_tag.attrib)
 sub_element.append(elem)
print ET.tostring(new_root_element)
print 'Done'`